# Search for word and get whole string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a listbox which looks like follows:

```
DANAHER -- 190,00 € -- 20 PCS -- 12:51:52.361
DANAHER -- 190,00 € -- 270 PCS -- 12:51:57.361
RENAULT -- 37,815 € -- 23 PCS -- 12:51:52.475
RENAULT -- 37,815 € -- 1 PCS -- 12:51:59.475
CAMECO -- 13,854 € -- 20 PCS -- 12:53:13.028
CAMECO -- 13,854 € -- 29 PCS -- 12:53:53.028
SAPSE -- 105,48 € -- 20 PCS -- 12:53:22.631
SAPSE -- 105,48 € -- 80 PCS -- 12:53:27.631
```

Now of course every second new companys are being added to the listbox, continously.
I wanted to create a textbox, where I can put in names of companys and it searchs through my listbox
if a entry exists, if one exists it shoud get the rest of the string and save it somewhere

Example of my textbox

```
DANAHER RENAULT
```

Desired output shall be:

```
DANAHER -- 190,00 € -- 20 PCS -- 12:51:52.361
DANAHER -- 190,00 € -- 270 PCS -- 12:51:57.361
RENAULT -- 37,815 € -- 23 PCS -- 12:51:52.475
RENAULT -- 37,815 € -- 1 PCS -- 12:51:59.475
```

What I have tried so far:

```
   string[] words = richTextBox2.Text.Split(' ');


                var toCheck = words;

               

                var newList = listwithentrys.Where(x => toCheck.Any(check => x.Contains(check)));
                List<String> selectedCollection = newList.ToList();
                listBox4.DataSource = selectedCollection;
```

But doesnt seem to work properly for no real reason.

Comment: Is `listwithentrys` the LisBox object? Is it is, `listwithentrys.Items.Cast<string>().Where(x => toCheck.Any(check => x.Contains(check)))` should work.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work properly" isn't a very clear definition of what the problem is. Can you explain more about how the result is wrong?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes sir its the main list

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean by "main list". See my edited top comment, you need to get a list of strings from the listbox, then you can query them with `Where`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when I use this code my results would be somehow manipulated when I have a company called SAP and another one called BAMSAP it would output both

Comment: Ok, `check => x.Trim().StartsWith(check)`? `check => x.Trim().StartsWith($"{check} ")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew check => x.Trim().StartsWith($"{check} ") seems to work :) thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since `listwithentrys` is a *ListBox* object, you need to get the lines first.

Then, you need to check if the lines *start with* an exact string from the `words` array. Since they all are followed with a space, you may simply check if the line starts with the word + a space.

```cs
var newList = listwithentrys.Items
    .Cast<string>()
    .Where(x => 
        toCheck.Any(check => x.Trim().StartsWith($"{check} "))
    )
```